# How to Map Object response to another ObjectDto in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have to map rest template response to my DTO with different key and values.
currently I am getting this json response from rest api

```
{
    "access_token": "7ada1efc-f159-42fa-84b9-f15b2a0ee333",
    "refresh_token": "1c9f5a71-40ae-4979-90db-088c2aa44123",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "scope": null,
    "expires_in": 1440
}
```

And I want to map it into my DTO for me able to save into DB

```
@Data
public class AuthIntegrationTokenDto {

    private long id;
    private int cmsIntegrationId;
    private String token;
    private String refreshToken;
    private String createdBy;
    private String lastUpdatedBy;

}
```

What i want is to get only same key dynamically to match with the response of api above.
Currently I am doing this but it seems that I am not setting correct value of same keys.

```
ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                request,
                Object.class,
                "client_credentials"
        );


        Object result = response.getBody();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject((Map) result);
        AuthIntegrationTokenDto authIntegrationTokenDto = new AuthIntegrationTokenDto();

        for (Object o : json.entrySet()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) o;

            authIntegrationTokenDto.setToken(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
            authIntegrationTokenDto.setRefreshToken(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));

        }
```

After executing this I am getting null values in my db.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the values to the DTO correctly. You must get the key first and then set it:

```
 for (Object o : json.entrySet()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) o;
            if(entry.getKey() == 'access_token') {
            authIntegrationTokenDto.setToken(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
            } else if(entry.getKey() == 'refresh_token') {
            authIntegrationTokenDto.setRefreshToken(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I found out that I am not setting my key first. Thanks to this.